# Why the property of an object would be undefined when it's assigned to the object?

Tags: javascript

```
var foo = {n: 1};
var bar = foo;
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
console.log(foo.x) // undefined
```

I realize that variables store objects as reference. Isn't that foo.x is just another variable? Why it can't point to the the reference as the object?

Comment: foo.x is now foo and foo has no property x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding what you did:

```
var foo = {n: 1}; // foo = ref#1
var bar = foo; // bar = ref#1
foo.x = foo = {n: 2}; // (ref#1) foo.x = foo (ref#2); foo = ref#2;
console.log(foo.x) // ref#2.x ... which is undefined (from ref#2)
console.log(bar.x)  // ref#2 ... which is ref#1
```

The key is that `foo.x` is evaluated *first*, which results in a reference to `ref#1` ... to which we then assign `ref#2`.

Comment: No, this is wrong. Did you try running this code?

Comment: @JLRishe - good point - fixed the reference labels to be correct.  Thanks!