# What is the value of foo.x?

Tags: javascript

Question: What is the value of foo.x?

My guess should be the same as foo, which should point to {n:2}. but when I run it through node, if give me `undefined`. Why?

```js
var foo = {n: 1};
var bar = foo;
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
```

Comment: Why was this question closed?

Comment: @LeoWilson It's been asked here before (several times actually)

Comment: @LeoWilson http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36684826 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34371980 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933210 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342809

Comment: @Paulpro That explains it.